# How to config timeout when using the RPC interface of aria2?

Tags: python, download, aria2

I'm using the `xmlrpclib` of Python to interact with `aria2` to manage files to download.

In the [documentation](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#rpc-interface), the only option that's shown in example is: `dir`.

I can also use `out` to specify the filename, now I wonder how to config things like `-timeout` and `--connect-timeout`.

I've tried `timeout` and `connect_timeout`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set timeout on the `socket` library level:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(<your_value>)
```

This value will be used by `xmlrpclib`.